# Use RequireJS to include a class defined using ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ecmascript-6

I have an existing project (which is run fully in the browser, no server-side component) which uses RequireJS to manage dependencies. Previously the way I'd been defining "classes" (including inheritance) was like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'classes/SomeParentClass',
], function($, SomeParentClass){

    function ThisClass(data){

        SomeParentClass.call(this, data);

        this.init = function(data){
            //Do stuff
        }

        this.init(data);
    }

    ThisClass.prototype = Object.create(SomeParentClass.prototype);
    ThisClass.prototype.constructor = ThisClass;

    return ThisClass;

});
```

And then when I wanted to include it in some other class I'd use the standard RequireJS define/require syntax:

```
define(['classes/ThisClass'], function(ThisClass){
    var fooInstance = new ThisClass(fooData);
});
```

I wanted to try my hand at the "class" syntax in ES6, so I set about converting one of my existing classes (I started with a "static" class for simplicity). It currently looks something like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
], function($){

    class SomeClass {

        static someStaticFn(){
            //Do whatever
        }
    }

});
```

Where I'm stymied currently is **how to reference SomeClass (with the new ES6 syntax) using RequireJS**. Assuming that's even possible.

**UPDATE**

As others have pointed out below, returning the class is all RequireJS cares about. I could have sworn that I already tried that, but sure enough it worked.

In case anyone else is a dummy like me and ends up here under similar circumstances, I want to also point out that I did have some success with the [requirejs-babel](https://github.com/mikach/requirejs-babel) plugin, however only **after** I'd re-written my class to use ES6 *export* and *import* statements instead of RequireJS's *define*. After having done that, anywhere else I was including the class I had to do it like so:

```
define(['es6!ThisClass'], function(ThisClass){ ...
```

I ended up choosing to modify a class that was included in **every** other module, so adding all those "es6!" strings turned out to be quite a drag. Although [this article](https://medium.com/lexical-labs-engineering/porting-your-javsascript-to-es6-d820520e900d) on porting existing projects to ES6 mentions a way of automating the process via RequireJS config.

However, as requirejs-babel transpiles the ES6 code at runtime, I will probably not incorporate that into my project at this time. If I do decide I want to go whole hog with ES6 I'd probably use "regular" [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or possibly [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

Comment: It doesn't make any difference to RequireJS whether the class is defined using `function` or `class` syntax. You just have to always `return` it from your module definition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ES6 Class is just a sugarcoat and still with same implementation underneath. You can use it the old way as creating class by function. Also be careful with browser compatibility https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/.

```
define([
    'jquery',
], function($){

    return class SomeClass {

        static someStaticFn(){
            //Do whatever
        }
    }

});
```